# How to access a MTOM payload when using document oriented SOAP?

Tags: soap, cxf, spring-ws, mtom, document-oriented

I need to integrate an external SOAP Service into my system. I have only the wsdl and no test server so far. I figured out how to generate stubs for the server using CXF in order to build a mocking server to implement against.

On the client side the spring webservices WebServiceTemplate seems the perfect match for my use case. Two of the methods are sending MTOM attachments as a result. And I'm not sure what I will see when looking at the response documents. Does spring-ws handle the attachment tranparently? Or do I need to access it in a special way?

And how do I generate an MTOM attachment on the server with my CXF generated classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring-WS operates over an underlying SOAP implementation, either SAAJ or Axiom. SAAJ is the default, but I don't think it supports MTOM (but I'm happy to be corrected on that). Axiom is the low-level SOAP implementation from Apache Axis2, and it *does* support MTOM.

So I'd recommend reading up on Spring-WS's support for Axiom, and Axiom's support for MTOM.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it a few weeks ago. Indeed using Axiom is the way to go. You just need to know that an OMText has a getDataHandler() method via which you can request the attachment data stream.